# Upstart start exits with status 1 so Chef aborts run

Tags: chef-infra, upstart, aws-opsworks, amazon-linux

I am deploying a server using Chef 11.10; the operating system is Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03 (we use EC2/OpsWorks), which uses Upstart.

In our recipe we trigger a start of the server, because we need it running to issue some configuration commands. Unfortunately, this fail if the server is already running because in that case `sudo start <job>` returns `1` instead of `0` (i.e. it's not idempotent).

It looks like Chef is not handling this case, or not checking if the server is already running.

What would be an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

11.4 is something like 3 or 4 years old at this point. Please try with a non-ancient version to see if we've fixed this at some point in the last half-decade.

Comment: it's actually 11.10, I updated the question. That said, I'll try and investigate

Comment: Same problem, we're 2-3 weeks from the release of Chef 13 just to give you context, and Chef 12 was a now-infamously long release cycle.